# Accessing Session variables between two servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception, session-variables

I have two servlets. In the first servlet I'm retrieving the userId from the database and store it in this session variable:

```
String uId = function.getLogin(username, password); //method getting the id

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("userId", uId); // here I'm setting the session variable with the id
```

Now in the second servlet I want to retrieve that userId from the session variable, but a java.lang.NullPointerException is being thrown.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
String uId = session.getAttribute("userId").toString();
int userId = Integer.parseInt(uId); //this is the code that I'm using in the second servlet, and throwing the NullPointerException
```

Am I'm doing something wrong please? Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you check/print the value of `uId` before the cast?

Comment: Is `function.getLogin(username, password)` returning null?

Comment: No, I'm using the same session variable in a JSP page and I have no problems there..

Comment: Are the servlets in the same webapp? Are you using the same browser to invoke the two servlets. How much time do you wait between the two calls? Why don't you use an Integer everywhere for the userId, since it seems to be an Integer?

Comment: It only creates a new session if there isn't already one for this client.

Comment: @zbindigonzales: it creates a new session only if there is none already existing. It shouldn't matter much here, unless the session has timed out.

Comment: Are you sure this is the line throwing the NPE, because it's impossible for Integer.parseInt to throw an NPE. All it throws is a NumberFormatException.

Comment: 1. Check servlet invocation order. 2. Session may be explicitly invalidated before second servlet was called, please check this.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for the information. "If there is no current session and create is true, returns a new session". Printed in the java doc :)

Comment: If the attribute is null I would expect the toString() to throw the NullPointerException. Is it definitely thrown on the line with the parseInt? As Viruzzo said above, can you print uId before you do the parseInt?

Comment: No I could not, therefore the toString() is throwing the exception...

Comment: Your servlets are dealing with two different sessions.

Comment: when the null pointer exception is thrown, you should see the line number which pinpoints where the null pointer is found.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the exception which should give you the line number of the NPE.  In terms of your code:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

Request could be null.  This is highly unlikely.

```
String uId = session.getAttribute("userId").toString();
```

The session could be null.   This means that the client is not sending back the session cookie or maybe you have multiple frontends and another one recorded the session.  We would need more information to be able to figure out what the problem is there.

It could also be that `session.getAttribute("userId")` is returning null.  I'd say this is most likely.  Maybe it is a different session where the `session.setAttribute("userId", uId);` was called.  Or maybe your initial call to `function.getLogin(username, password);` returned null so you were setting `null` in the session?

```
// this is the code that [... is] throwing the NullPointerException
int userId = Integer.parseInt(uId);
```

You are incorrect.  As I read the Java 1.6 code, `parseInt` will never throw NPE.  Here's the first line in that method:

```
if (s == null) {
    throw new NumberFormatException("null");
}
```

I bet there is something wrong with your session.  I would suggest using the debugger to figure out what is set incorrectly.  Printf-debugging would also help.

Answer (score 0):

In setting the attribute you must ensure that upto then no response is written. Furthermore that after that the response is written (no exception).